# Same code from support7Demos behaves different on different devices on AppCompat DayNight Mode 23.2.0

Tags: android-appcompat

I have downloaded the Android Support 23.2.0 and imported support7Demos under directory /Android/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos without making any changes. After importing the necessary dependencies, it builds successfully and generate an apk. I installed the apk on Smartisan T1 with API 19. The day night mode works as expected. But it does not work on Nexus 5 with API 23.

Please be noticed that the code is from the Android official Support V7 sample, I did not make any changes at all.
The same apk installed on different devices work different.

This is the link to download the [apk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-UakqPK0VCdZ1p1cVFaQm5OOEU/view) to check it out.
You could also check out the [two videos](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-UakqPK0VCdZjFlQnFfSEl0SDg&usp=drive_web) that recorded to see the difference.

Is it a bug? And if it is a bug, is there any workaround?

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35701225/859190

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36005465/2826147).

Answer (score 0):

To those who still wonders the answer, here it is :

> It's issue with AppCompatActivity.java of support library which is fixed now.

It is the official answer quoted from the bug logged in [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201910)